# How to prevent partial view loaded several times to load several Javascript code

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, frameworks

I'm using Inter App Framework with my application. my question regards behaviour of MVC in general...

If i'm loading view / partial view into div using Ajax, 
and that view contains html markup and javascript,
how do i prevent the javascript code from loading more than once.

the framework replaces ALL the divs html content but i think the javascript code is stayed at the DOM so while using the App it gets slower and blowned by each load.
thank.

Answer (score 0):

usually MVC's have different view templates and usually you'd happen to define one specifically for ajax, which contains no header/footer/javascripts/css files or anything that shouldn't be there.
check your MVC for custom template definition for views.